# Adding na.rm as a parameter to a custom function in r

Tags: r, na

I have written a Fun that I use to normalize a set of numbers from 0 to 5.
but I have NAs as part of my data and would like the Fun to skip them and move to the next value.

I have tried this code:

```
IDNO<-1:11
Scores<-c(1:10,NA)
ScoreDF<-as.data.frame(cbind(IDNO,Scores))
Normalize.Final.Score.fun <- function(x){
  5*(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
}

ScoreDF<-ScoreDF %>% 
  mutate(BotanicalVal=Normalize.Final.Score.fun(Scores))
```

I expect the output to be as I would get running this line:

```
ScoreDF$ExpectedBotanicalVal<- c(Normalize.Final.Score.fun(Scores[1:10]),"NA")
```

> [1] "0"                 "0.555555555555556" "1.11111111111111"   [4]
>   "1.66666666666667"  "2.22222222222222"  "2.77777777777778"   [7]
>   "3.33333333333333"  "3.88888888888889"  "4.44444444444444"  [10] "5"
>   "NA"

Whereas I get only NAs. 
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `min(x, na.rm=TRUE)` / `max(x, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: In the function definition `function(x, na.rm = TRUE)` then in the function `min(x, na.rm = na.rm)` and the same for `max`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `na.rm = TRUE` to your calls

```
Normalize.Final.Score.fun <- function(x) {
  5 * (x - min(x, na.rm = TRUE)) / (max(x, na.rm = TRUE) - min(x, na.rm = TRUE))
}
```